# How to make divs fill the width of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I want my `div`s(`.give`, `.sep`, `.take`) to fill its parent(`.trade`)'s width.

HTML code:

```html
<div class="trade">
  <div class="give"></div>
  <div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="take"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.trade {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.give,
.take {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sep {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But, `.give,.take{width:auto;}` did not fill it.

I also tried:

```css
.give,
.take {
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
}
.sep {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
.give {
  left: 0;
}
.take {
  right: 0;
}
```

But `.give` and `.take` invaded `.sep`'s place.

How can I make it? I don't want to use Javascript if possible.

+) `.give{margin-right:10px;} .take{margin-left:10px;}` or `.give{padding-right:10px;} .take{padding-left:10px;}` didn't work and just expanded their width.

Comment: Forget about position,inline-block and float. Use grid or flex,it is their purpose. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the intended result? `flexbox` makes this fairly straightforward... The borders and the padding on `.trade` are for visual aid only

```css
.trade{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-content:center;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:1rem;
  margin:0 auto;
  float:none;
  
  width:80%;
  height:10rem;
}


.trade div{
  border:1px solid black;
  flex:1
}

.trade div:before{
  content:attr(class)
}
```

```html
<div class="trade">
  <div class="give"></div>
  <div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="take"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As of now I will worship FLEX

Answer (score 1):

As said by G-Cyrillus, you shouldn't try to hack with `float`. `inline-block` is also completely unecessary and far to complicated for your purpose in this case.

The real tool is `Flexbox`. Add `.trade { display: flex; }` to the CSS to use flexbox.

Then you can use `.give, .take { flex-grow: 1; }` to make them extend to fill the entire parents width equally. Instead of using margins to seperate your 3 child elements, you can use `.trade { column-gap: 20px; }` instead.

```css
.trade {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.sep {
  width: 20px;
}

.give,
.take {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* added for demonstration */

.trade {
  background-color: red;
}

.give,
.sep,
.take {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="trade">
  <div class="give"></div>
  <div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="take"></div>
</div>
```